# How to open url in safari from setting bundle by clicking on a cell of it?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to open a web page in safari or other web browser by clicking on a cell which is in the setting.bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

I just read the [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) and found

***you use the NSUserDefaults class to access preference values from your code***

<s>I don't think you can perform some actions on that.</s>

I just saw `Nike + iPod` app setting in settings app and they have done the same, so it's is possible to do that, I don't know the way to do it right now but once I know I'll update my answer again.

---

<s>NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yoururl.com"];</s>

[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

For how to create setting pane/handle it's call back you can read [this tutorial](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/)

Comment: I am trying to find open url from setting bundle.